# Stargazer: reorder statistics of regression output

Tags: r, regression, lm, stargazer

until now, I cannot figure out how to reorder the statistics shown in the table of a regression object. To be specific, I estimated a model using the lm() function and now I create a table using Stargazer. Next, I would like to reorder the variables in the statistics section. That is, I would like to display the R-Squared before showing the number of observations. Does anyone know how to do that, or if it is even possible?

Right now, the output looks like:

```
---------------------------------------------------
Linear Trend                        Yes            
Quadratic Trend                     Yes            
Observations                       1,425           
R2                                 0.060           
Adjusted R2                        0.050           
Residual Std. Error          0.162 (df = 1410)     
F Statistic              5.960*** (df = 15; 1410)  
===================================================
Note:                   *p<0.1; **p<0.05; ***p<0.01
```

but I want it to show like:

```
---------------------------------------------------
Linear Trend                        Yes            
Quadratic Trend                     Yes                       
R2                                 0.060           
Adjusted R2                        0.050
Observations                       1,425           
Residual Std. Error          0.162 (df = 1410)     
F Statistic              5.960*** (df = 15; 1410)  
===================================================
Note:                   *p<0.1; **p<0.05; ***p<0.01
```

or whatever order I desire.

Comment: It doesn't look like it's easy (`keep.stat()` doesn't respond to the ordering of the arguments).  You could use `omit.stat="all"` and then add all the stats in you want with the `add.lines` argument.

Comment: Then I would have to compute them manually before, right?

Comment: Correct, though you could write a function that takes the models as inputs and produces the appropriate list of vectors to pass to `add.lines`.